# time series in R, unwanted variable class changes

Tags: r, time-series

I'm trying to program the Coppock Curve in R and finding time series exceedingly difficult to work with in R. The S&P 500 data can be downloaded from finance.yahoo.com. Just bring in the date and the adjusted close.

```
sp500 = read.csv(file="/.../sp500.csv",header=TRUE)
attach(zoo)
sp500.z = zoo(sp500)
lag11 = lag(sp500.z$SP500, -11, na.pad=TRUE)  
lag14 = lag(sp500.z$SP500, -14, na.pad=TRUE)
sp500.z = cbind(sp500.z, lag11, lag14)
str(sp500.z)
sp500.z[1:25,]
data = (sp500.z)
data[1:25,]  ### everything looks good up to here
str(data)

data = as.data.frame(data) ### problem arises here, everything becomes factor even if it wasn't before, so I try to convert, but it doesn't work
data$SP500 = as.numeric(data$SP500)
data$lag11 = as.numeric(data$lag11)
data$lag14 = as.numeric(data$lag14)
data$date = as.Date(data$date)
```

In order to do further data manipulation I need to convert to a data frame, because you cannot attach a zoo matrix or perform dataset$variable operations on it. When I convert to data frame the lag11 and lag14 variables turn into index numbers. The data frame conversion makes everything a factor, and when the variable types are corrected the problem occurs.

The Coppock Curve is calculated as a 10-month weighted moving average of the sum of the 14-month rate of change and the 11-month rate of change for the index.

Coppock Curve = 10-month weighted MA(of 14-month ROC + 11-month ROC)

Where the ROC is:

ROC = [(Close - Close n periods ago) / (Close n periods ago)] * 100

where n is 11 and 14. The weights on the ROC terms go backwards in time from 10/55 for period t, 9/55 for t-1,..., 1/55 for t-9.

Comment: Using `attach` is a bad idea and if z is a zoo object with multiple columns and x is one of those columns then z$x does work.  Please make your code reproducible.

Answer (score 2):

You do not *need* to convert to a data.frame. While you cannot use `$` on a matrix, you *can* use it on zoo and xts objects. And you really shouldn't be using `attach`, especially if this is something you plan to put into a reusable script.

What you want to do is very easy with xts/zoo, quantmod, and TTR.

```
library(quantmod) # also loads TTR, xts, and zoo
# download data from Yahoo Finance
sp500 <- getSymbols("^GSPC", auto.assign=FALSE)
# convert to monthly
sp500m <- to.monthly(sp500)
# add lags (via $<-, like you claimed couldn't be done)
sp500m$lag11 <- ROC(Ad(sp500m), n=11, type="discrete")
sp500m$lag14 <- ROC(Ad(sp500m), n=14, type="discrete")
# calculate Coppock Curve
sp500m$Coppock <- WMA(sp500m$lag11 + sp500m$lag14, n=10, wts=(9:1)/55)
```

Comment: Joshua - Thx, I'm relatively new to R coming from SAS. I will try out your script.  Spike2037

Answer (score 0):

One option would be not to put the data into `zoo` format and then use the `lag()` function in `dplyr` instead. So:

```
library(dplyr)
sp500 = read.csv(file="/.../sp500.csv",header=TRUE)
sp500.v2 <- sp500 %>%
    mutate(lag11 = lag(SP500, 11),
           lag14 = lag(SP500, 14))
```

Are these data grouped somehow, like maybe by ticker symbol? If so, you could accommodate that like this:

```
sp500.v2 <- sp500 %>%
    group_by([grouping variable name, no quotes]) %>%
    mutate(lag11 = lag(SP500, 11),
           lag14 = lag(SP500, 14))
```

And if the data aren't pre-sorted by date or you want to make sure that's done before you lag, you can use `arrange()` like so:

```
sp500.v2 <- sp500 %>%
    group_by([grouping variable name, no quotes]) %>%
    arrange([date variable]) %>%
    mutate(lag11 = lag(SP500, 11),
           lag14 = lag(SP500, 14))
```